# no such table -- django

Tags: database, django

I am using south, and I have syncdb but alas i get stuck with this database error, can you help me fix this and maybe tell me how to fix something like this in the future.

this missing database table error is comming up in  a couple of different places dealing with something called salesflow_contact I have a folder salesflow with a models.py file with a class of Contact with a capitol,

the error shown is from trying to post some content to the table, but i also get an error with the pagination view browsecontacts

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/addacontact

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'south',
 'sekizai')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/brian/projects/steprider/steprider/views.py" in Add_a_contact
  36.           new_contact = form.save(request.user)
File "/home/brian/projects/steprider/salesflow/forms.py" in save
  23.       contact.save()
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  909.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  872.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-0.9-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py" in pre_save
  135.         value = unicode(self.create_slug(model_instance, add))
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-0.9-py2.7.egg/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py" in create_slug
  122.         while not slug or queryset.filter(**kwargs):
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in __nonzero__
  130.             iter(self).next()
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in _result_iter
  118.                 self._fill_cache()
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in _fill_cache
  892.                     self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  291.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  763.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  818.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/brian/virt_env/virt_step/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  344.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /addacontact
Exception Value: no such table: salesflow_contact


#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  steprider.salesflow.forms.py
#  
#  Copyright 2012 BRIAN SCOTT CARPENTER <KlanestroTalisman@gmail.com>

from django.forms import ModelForm
from salesflow import models
from django import forms
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Contact
        exclude = ("user","slug")

    def save(self, user):
        contact = super(ContactForm, self).save(commit=False)
        contact.user = user
        contact.save()
        return contact

class Contact_History_Form:

    class Meta:
        model = models.Contact_History
        exclude = ("user","slug")






#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  views.py
#  
#  Copyright 2012 BRIAN SCOTT CARPENTER <KlanestroTalisman@gmail.com>
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from salesflow.forms import *
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from salesflow.models import Contact

def home (request):
    """ This is the Home view"""
    return render_to_response(('index.html') ,context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def server_error(request, template_name='templates/500.html'):
    """
    500 error handler.
    Templates: `500.html`
    Context:
    STATIC_URL
      Path of static media (e.g. "media.example.org")
    """
    t = loader.get_template(template_name)
    return HttpResponseServerError(
        t.render(Context({'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL})))

def Add_a_contact(request):
    """give them a page so they can donate and save it to a database."""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_contact = form.save(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(item, args=(new_contact.slug,)))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render_to_response('salesflow/addacontact.html',{'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def browse_contacts(request):
    contact_list = Contact.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list,15)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('salesflow/browsecontacts.html',
    {"contacts":contacts,
    "site":settings.SITE_DOMAIN},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Did you [convert_to_south](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/ConvertingAnApp) your app, and migrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward; you have no table called `salesflow_contact`.

You'd need to run `migrate` assuming it has the initial `schemamigration salesflow --initial` first table creation migration.

`syncdb` will not create tables for south-managed models, which is most likely your problem. You can bypass this with `syncdb --all` but if it's truly south-managed, you should run `migrate salesflow` and it should create the tables assuming you have the `schemamigration salesflow --initial` migration in there.